# Display the value of CSS property in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I implemented a progress bar using HTML and CSS. The value of the progress bar depends on the width of the inner class (in this code: bar-fill). I want to access this width property in my styling and display it next to the progress bar.

Working Code: https://jsfiddle.net/nvarun123/h5xgfyrp/3/

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="bar">
<span class="bar-fill"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.container{
  width:300px;
}
.bar{
  width:100%;
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.bar-fill{
  height:15px;
  display:block;
  background:#0073CF;
  width:60%;
  border-radius:7.5px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.8s ease;
  transition: width 0.8s ease;
}
```

Comment: In practice, the width of the progress bar will depend on some other data. You can treat the progress bar and the value in text as both different display methods for the underlying data. So, for example, you will have a variable that says `currentProgress = 60`. Based on that, you will make the progress bar take up 60% width, and you will also know to display the number "60" in the progress bar. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/h5xgfyrp/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

▶ First, you need to **add an HTML element that will show the progress:**

```
<div id = "progress"></div>
```

▶ Then, you can use the **following JavaScript code:**

```
var
    /* The elements */
    bar = document.getElementsByClassName("bar")[0],
    barFill = document.getElementsByClassName("bar-fill")[0],
    progress = document.getElementById("progress"),

    /* The bar's total width */
    barWidth = window.getComputedStyle(bar, null).getPropertyValue("width"),

    /* How much of the bar is filled */
    barFillWidth = window.getComputedStyle(barFill, null).getPropertyValue("width"),

    /* Create the percentage */
    pct = 100 * (parseFloat(barFillWidth) / parseFloat(barWidth)) + "%";

/* Set the innerHTML of our progress element */
progress.innerHTML = pct;
```

**Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5xgfyrp/7/) or the following snippet for a visual representation.**

**Snippet:**

```js
(function() {
  var
    bar = getByClass("bar"),
    barFill = getByClass("bar-fill"),
    progress = document.getElementById("progress"),
    barWidth = getWidth(bar),
    barFillWidth = getWidth(barFill),
    pct = 100 * barFillWidth / barWidth + "%";

  progress.innerHTML = pct;
  
  function getWidth(element) {
    return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("width"));
  };
  
  function getByClass(className) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
  }
})();
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.bar-fill {
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  background: #0073CF;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.8s ease;
  transition: width 0.8s ease;
}
#progress {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar">
    <span class="bar-fill"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="progress"></div>
```

---

**To position the label next to the progressbar**, there are a lot of things you can do. I'm mentioning two of them below:

1. You can put **`position: absolute`** to **`#progress`** to get it out of the normal flow, so that it can be **`'inline'`** with **`.bar`** as the bar currently occupies 100% of the container's width.
2. You can put **`#progress`** outside of the container as a sibling and put **`display: inline-block`** to both of them.

Comment: Is there anyway i can show the value percentage next to the progress bar?

Comment: @VarunNuthalapati check my answer as to why that might not be a good idea

Comment: Yes, you can use: **`display: inline-block`** in **`#progress`** in your CSS.

Comment: @AngelPolitis displaying the width percentage of the progress bar next to the bar itself will result in the bar not being a true 60%.. so the calculation will be off.

Comment: Not true @BviLLe_Kid. I'm editing the answer to show you.

Comment: @Angel Politis I've tried making the changes you've said, but they are not working https://jsfiddle.net/nvarun123/h5xgfyrp/9/

Comment: @AngelPolitis ahh you are using `getPropertyValue`, whereas I am using the actual `width` property. Idk how I didn't notice that

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help @VarunNuthalapati

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid that's why I'm using **`getPropertyValue`** :)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the percent width of the `.bar-fill` by dividing it's width and the width of `.bar`

```
var percent = ($('.bar-fill').width() / $('.bar').width()) * 100
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/fve4qszo/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve what you are looking for, but there could be some trouble when you say:

*and display it next to the progress bar.*

Because if you display the percentage next to the progress bar, then the width of the progress bar is no longer a *true* 60%.. it goes down a few percentage points to allow you to display the percentage of the bar next to it. So, with that said please be careful and be mindful of what you are trying to accomplish or else this could become frustrating.

Here is the formula that is used to get the width percentage:

```
var n = $('.bar-fill').width() / $('.bar-fill').parent().width() * 100;
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqpvusak/3/).

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the progress bar just using javascript and you're using jquery. But thanks for your answer, it works. I'm using javascript for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width value using

```
document.querySelector('.bar-fill').offsetWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

First add the jquery script link in your html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="bar">
<span class="bar-fill"></span> 
</div>
</div>
Test
```

In your javascript ypu can get the width of bar-fill class by following:

```
var width = $(".bar-fill").css('width');
$(".container").prepend(width);
```